# How to float two spans inside a centered div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to put a div inside an area and keep it vertically centered, and then inside of it have two spans, one floated to the left, and the other to the right. But I can't seem to get the spans to do both things at the same time. I'm doing this in React, but I don't *think* that would make a difference, but I'm including it to explain the syntax.

I had this first:

```
<ResultsHeader>
    <span style={{ float: 'left'}}>Results</span>
    <span style={{ float: 'right' }}{props.results.length} items found</span>
</ResultsHeader>
```

Then I have ResultsHeader defined as:

```
const ResultsHeader = styled('div')({
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor:'#CCCCCC',
    color: '#686868',
    display: 'flex',
    height: 60,
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 20
});
```

When I do that, I get all the span text over to the left, e.g. `Results4 items found`. If I change the display to `'block'`, the spans are correctly floated, but the text is no longer centered vertically. Instead, it's all at the top of the div's area.

I've tried other display options (e.g. `'inline-flex'`) and they're even worse. I can't find any display option that makes sense for this. I even tried adding another span to wrap the two floated ones, and tried mixing `'block'` and `'flex'` displays between it and the ResultsHeader element, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> keep it vertically centered, and then inside of it have two spans,
>   one floated to the left, and the other to the right.

You can achieve that layout with just `flexbox`, you do not need to use `float`.

1. Remove `float: left` and `float: right`
2. Add `justifyContent: "space-between"` to `ResultsHeader`

---

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span >Results</span>
  <span> items found</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `float` property is ignored in a `display: flex` parents 
Use flex property instead, `justify-content: space-between`, on the container